# Hazelcast low performance putting 10 000 items for 6 seconds

Tags: scala, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I [got an example](https://github.com/Sergey80/hazelcast-steps-to/blob/master/src/test/scala-2.10/test/CacheTest.scala), where I'm testing hazelcast performance for simple cases.

I have 4 cores machine, 1.2 GHz on each.

I'm sending 100 bunches by 100 "clients" (actually just lopp in one thread).

So in the end I have **10 000** bunches of tickets.

The performance is about:

- **6 seconds** if I use `putAsync`
- and **10 seconds**, if I use: `set`

I  consider this as low performance.

**Questions:**
Is it?
How could I improve it?

All code is there - [configs](https://github.com/Sergey80/hazelcast-steps-to/blob/master/src/main/resources/hazelcast.xml). scala, sbt project

**Update:**

Running time= test time:

- **10 000** - takes 1-2 seconds for newer machine. For older  machine: 10
  seconds
- **40 000** - 18 secons for older machine and 4 for newer
- **250 000** - 100 seconds for older machine and  20-24 seconds for
  newer.

So "how long time" = test time.

Where: newer machine is: 8 cores 2.2 Ghz
Older machine: 4 cores, 1,2 Hgz

Quite big difference in performance depending on machine.

Comment: Have you tried `putAll`?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a single node cluster?

To give you an idea; on our old test lab with 4 dual socket sandybridge boxes with 24 ht threads and 1GbE card, we can easily do 300/400k inserts per second.

If we do readonly operation, the performance is +/- 700k ops/second since we don't need to deal with a backup.

This is member only setup; client will be a bit slower.

The putAsync should be very fast (although I don't know much about the client). The putAsync allows the IO pipelines to be filled up nicely and you can lift on top of a batching effect.

Comment: this is what it says in config. i guess it is. that's why I put complet project to show how it looks/work. in my simple case 10 000  / 6 sec  = 1 600 inserts per second. 1.6k / per second

Comment: I should say that on another machine, with 8 cores (2 times more)  +1 more GHz on each core it takes 1-3 seconds.

Comment: How long are you running the test? Because in the beginning the performance of any JVM based application will be terrible due to the JIT not have kicked in.

Comment: Have it run for 5 or 10 minutes. I tried to check your source code, but I don't see any when I follow your link. 

Performance depends on a lot of factors, but the numbers you have given appear to be quite low. But I'm missing information to say anything sensible about it.